# Can I hide categories from the actively displayed list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a long list of categories, a lot of which I don't actively use:

[image: lots of categories in drop-down]

I don't want to *delete* any categories because I do have lots of search folders, etc that make use of old categories. But I'd like to be able to remove the ones I don't use often from the right-click context menu of categories.

Is there a way to hide these categories from this drop-down list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Outlook controls this list automatically by following its own internal rules (15 most used).

Comment: So what you're saying is, I don't use *enough* categories? :)

Comment: Something like that =)